# Which are the Biblical references summarising early Christian Community life?

Tags: greek, acts, christianity

Text of a Sunday School lesson speaks of four Greek terms that summarize early Christian community life. The words are:

- Koinonia meaning Fellowship;
- Diaconia meaning Service;
- Kerygma meaning Preaching of the Gospel and
- Eucharistia meaning Thanksgiving.

(I am not sure if any term has been left out).

My question is: which are the Biblical references from which the above terms have been derived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are references in the New Testament of *koinonia*, *diakonia*, *kerygma*, and *eucharista*.

- Acts 2:42 – koinonia (fellowship)
- Acts 6:4, Acts 11:29 – diakonia (ministry, service)
- Mark 16:20; 1 Corinthians 2:4 – kerygma (preaching)
- 1 Corinthians 14:16 – eucharistia (thankfulness)

Also note that other passages in the scriptures record additional activities of the early church.

- Acts 4:32,34 – The believers had all things in common so there was not a needy person among them.
- Acts 4:33 – The apostles were giving their testimony to the resurrection
- Acts 5:16 – The apostles healed everyone who was brought to them.
- Acts 6:4 – The apostles devoted themselves to preaching the Word and prayer.
- Acts 20:7 – The believers gathered together on the first day of the week (Sunday) to break bread and listen to teaching.

The apostle Paul mentions the gifts of the Holy Spirit in 1 Corinthians 12 as a participatory ministry by and to the church.

Let me recommend to you a book that describes the teachings and activities of the first Christians: *The Early Christians in Their Own Words* by Eberhard Arnold, originally published in 1926.

Let me also recommend *The Didache*, which was likely distributed among Christians before 100 AD. In the introduction, this document includes basic instructions to new believers concerning abstinence from food sacrificed to idols, baptism, fasting, prayer, the eucharistic thanksgiving, fragrant anointing, and the approved teacher.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 ... and thanks for the additional references. Didache is not only useful but fascinating as an example of an early Christian manual of discipline.

Comment: Currently, I'm rereading Jeremy C. Jackson's brilliant book, *No Other Foundation, The Church Through Twenty Centuries* (1980), which Francis Schaffer described as "The finest book available on church history." This book, like no other focuses on the spirit of the church through the centuries rather than on church celebrities and politics. Especially valuable in my opinion are the beliefs, practices, and challenges in the early church and how these changed over time.

Answer (score 3):

This question is likely to be closed because it is simply searching for a text.  However, in the spirit of helpfulness I offer the following:

- κοινωνία (koinónia) see  https://biblehub.com/greek/2842.htm
- διακονία (diakonia) see  https://biblehub.com/greek/1248.htm
- κηρύσσω (kérussó) see  https://biblehub.com/greek/2784.htm
- εὐχαριστία (eucharistia) see  https://biblehub.com/greek/2169.htm

However, I also suggest you look at

- λειτουργία (leitourgia) see  https://biblehub.com/greek/3009.htm
- εὐαγγελίζω (euaggelizó) see  https://biblehub.com/greek/2097.htm
- προσευχή (proseuché) see  https://biblehub.com/greek/4335.htm
- διδάσκω (didaskó) see  https://biblehub.com/greek/1321.htm

I suggest your original list is a little simplistic and short.

Comment: + 1 thank God for the spirit of helpfulness sneaking these answers in before the spirit of the rules blocked them ;-)

Comment: +1 Likewise, I deeply appreciate the spirit of helpfulness without which "And if I have prophetic powers, and understand all mysteries and all knowledge, and if I have all faith, so as to remove mountains, but have not love, I am nothing." - 1 Corinthians 13:2 ESV

Comment: Thanks, Dottard for the well resources inputs. Let us keep in mind that the one who asks questions on BHE could also be charitable. He may already know the answer, but may still pose the question so that newcomers be enlightened.

Answer (score 0):

Often, it seems that Sunday School lessons reduce the hermeneutics of the scriptures, which contextually, linguistically, and culturally can be very deep and challenging, into simplified catechisms.

My personal experience, the results of this teaching was narrow, shallow, and unfulfilling. It could be compared to a course on cooking that teaches only the five basic tastes of salt, sweet, bitter, sour, and umami. Memorize those and you’re all set to be a chef, right?

Let’s take one of the terms, *eucharistia*, from the question asked.

From that term, we get the Eucharist, interpreted either as a sacrament or as an ordinance. Tracing its history, we can see that it originated in the Jewish Passover celebration that now culminated in the *Afikomen*, which seems to have been added by the early Messianic Jews from Jesus’ own words in John 26:26-28 ESV

> Now as they were eating, Jesus took bread, and after blessing it broke
> it and gave it to the disciples, and said, “Take, eat; this is my
> body.” And he took a cup, and when he had given thanks he gave it to
> them, saying, “Drink of it, all of you, for this is my blood of the
> covenant, which is poured out for many for the forgiveness of sins.

Jeremy Jackson in his brilliant book, *No Other Foundation, The Church Through Twenty Centuries*, pointed out the change of *eucharistia* from **tables** (plural) where the early Christians assembled and ate a love meal together weekly in thanksgiving and remembrance, to a single **table** where the bishop performed the rite of Holy Communion to congregants, to something now called an **altar** with a priest separated from the congregation by an altar rail.

Dr. Jackson associates this change with the Christian church emerging from severe persecution under several Roman Emperors, first to Roman governmental tolerance, then acceptance, and finally to mandatory participation to the *exclusion* of all other religions.

The result was the explosive growth of barely nominal Christians in a church that responded with a necessary consolidation of ecclesiastical power under bishops to maintain any sense of doctrinal cohesion. Even then, there were many heretical teachers and leaders--and still are.

All this from a single term, *eucharistia*, in the original question!